# VBA Excel file size containing multiple pivot tables is huge

Tags: excel, vba

I am automating the process of creating pivot tables in excel. The problem I have is that the pivot tables I create using my macro is way larger than the ones I create manually. Both of the pivot tables look identical but there is a great difference in file size.

[image: IMG1]

As seen in the image above, the one created by my macro is about 6 times larger! I suspect that it is the way I cache for the data when creating my pivot tables. So, here is the general code I use to create my pivot tables.

```
Sub pivottable1()

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet, DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PField As PivotField
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim PvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim PTName As String

    SheetName = "MySheetName1"
    PTName = "PivotTable1"
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(SheetName).Delete
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set PSheet = Worksheets(SheetName)
    Set DSheet = Worksheets(1)

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(4, 1), _
    TABLENAME:=PTName)

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TABLENAME:=PTName)

    Sheets(SheetName).Select
        Set PvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PTName)
        'Rows
        With PvtTable.PivotFields("TypeCol")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With PvtTable.PivotFields("NameCol")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With

        'Columns
        With PvtTable.PivotFields("CategoryCol")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        'Values
        PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("Values1"), "Value Balance", xlSum
        PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("Values2"), "Value 2 Count", xlCount

        With PvtTable
            .PivotFields("TypeCol").ShowDetail = False
            .TableRange1.Font.Size = 10
            .ColumnRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .ColumnRange.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .ColumnRange.WrapText = True
            .ColumnRange.Columns.AutoFit
            .ColumnRange.EntireRow.AutoFit
            .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
            .ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
            .PivotFields("TypeCol").AutoSort xlDescending, "Value Balance" 'Sort descdending order
            .PivotFields("NameCol").AutoSort xlDescending, "Value Balance"
        End With

        'Change Data field (Values) number format to have thousand seperator and 0 decimal places.
        For Each PField In PvtTable.DataFields
            PField.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        Next PField

End Sub
```

This is how I create 6 different pivot tables which all uses the same source of data which is located in the same workbook and is in the first worksheet of that workbook. So, for example my second pivot table macro code would look something like this.

```
Sub pivottable2()

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet, DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PField As PivotField
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim PvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim PTName As String

    SheetName = "MySheetName2"
    PTName = "PivotTable2"
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(SheetName).Delete
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set PSheet = Worksheets(SheetName)
    Set DSheet = Worksheets(1)

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(4, 1), _
    TABLENAME:=PTName)

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TABLENAME:=PTName)

    Sheets(SheetName).Select
        Set PvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PTName)
        'Rows
        With PvtTable.PivotFields("ManagerCol")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With PvtTable.PivotFields("IDCol")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With

        'Columns
        With PvtTable.PivotFields("CategoryCol")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        'Values
        PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("Values1"), "Value Balance", xlSum

End Sub
```

All that I change would be the macro name, the worksheet name, the pivot table name and the input rows/columns/data values for the pivot table.

What I hope to accomplish is to reduce the file size of my macro created pivot tables, to something similar of the ones I create manually.

If there is anything extra that you guys would like to know, please comment. I will make an edit with the question and add the details respectively.

Comment: Could it be that the VBA itself is causing the code to be that large, and if you would place the code in WorkBook_Macro and run the code from the code workbook on to data workbook you'll manage to reduce the size? Because the way it is now I highly advise you not to use that code (but thanks for publishing it anyways!)

Comment: @HilaDG "Could it be that the VBA itself is causing the code to be that large" not too sure what you mean by this but I am pretty sure it's the way I cache the data for the pivot table when creating them that causes such a big difference in the file size. The code I used is what I believe the most common way in building a pivot table found on the internet. It creates a separate cache for each pivot table, instead of  sharing them between each other. I am wondering, how would I readjust the code so that the pivot tables I create all share the same data cache? :)

Comment: Looks like your code creates two pivotables for each Sub - one at A4 and one at A1 - is that intentional?  You can just create a single pivotcache and point each of your pivottables at that one cache - did you try that?

Comment: @TimWilliams "Looks like your code creates two pivotables for each Sub" Oh, nice catch. That was a mistake on my part. I excluded the two extra lines of code that creates another pivot table in a different position. This does not have any affect on the file size however. "You can just create a single pivotcache and point each of your pivottables at that one cache", how would I do this exactly? Do I have to include both these macros into a new subroutines so that they are able to share the same cache?

Comment: @DSM I meant that the code itself is taking some space, and that's probably why (in the answer posted below) there's a slight difference between the manual and the automatic versions. BTW please accept the answer below since it looks like the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same pivotcache for multiple pivottables (assuming they're based on the same source data).

Untested:

```
'creates and returns a shared pivotcache object
Function GetPivotCache() As PivotCache
    Static pc As PivotCache 'static variables retain their value between calls
    Dim pRange As Range

    If pc Is Nothing Then 'create if not yet created
        Set prRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
                     (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pRange)
    End If
    Set GetPivotCache = pc
End Function


Sub pivottable1()

    '...
    '...

    Set PSheet = Worksheets(SheetName)

    Set PCache = GetPivotCache() '<<< will be created if needed

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
                   (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:=PTName)

    '...
    '...

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, looks like you have shared an answer! I will try it and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: I have applied the code into my macros. I am happy to say that the size has been significantly reduced to almost about the same size as the manual one! There is a question I have about the GetPivotCache function and the static variable as I am not familiar on how it works. Lets say, I create 6 pivot tables which uses data found in worksheet 1 as how this thread's question is structured. What if I have another 6 pivot table that uses data in worksheet 2. I won't be able to use the same function for the next 6 pivot tables as the pivot cache stores the data of worksheet 1, right?

Comment: Yes - currently there's a specific range defined in that function.  You can either copy it and change the range in the copy, or it would be possible to make a single function to which you'd pass the source range to be used, but that might be a bit more complex than you need....

Comment: "it would be possible to make a single function  to which you'd pass the source range to be used", I did make a few changes to your answer so that the `GetPivotCache` function takes in a range of the data so that it wouldn't have to be defined in the function itself. If we were to use a single function, would we have to check if the data range is different in order to create a new cache? I agree that it is more than what the question asks for as I structured it to capture  the base of the problem. Should I be asking this in a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior before.  By the very nature of creating Pivots, your WB will bloat up, just as you are seeing now.  In the past I have used VBA to create the Pivots, exactly like you are doing, and then right at the end, run a small script to do copy all, and paste special values.  That will eliminate most, and perhaps all, of the bloat.  Also, instead of saving your WB as XLSX, try XLSB, which will be around 4x smaller than XLSX and open/close around 4x faster than XLSX.  I'm wondering why you are even using XLSX, because you can't save Macros in that format.  Or, maybe you have a template WB that does all the work, and you simply save new reports as XLSX.  Anyway, consider using the XLSB format from now on.

Comment: Hi there! " I'm wondering why you are even using XLSX, because you can't save Macros in that format." You are right. I have my macros saved in an excel add in file so that the macro runs in any opened workbook. "a small script to do copy all, and paste special values", I did consider this as an option at first, but since the file size was considerable when I did it manually, I wanted to look for ways to keep the pivot tables as is but also have the file size close to what is achievable when done manually.

Comment: I suspected it was the way I cached data used for the pivot table which made me raise this question on how I could share the same cached data among various pivot tables. Sometimes I have 2-3 different data sources, which 20-24 pivot tables are derived from. Creating a separate cache for 20 pivot tables would be crazy! The answer that @Tim Williams provided is exactly what I need, but the data range changes due to updates in the data worksheet or just using a different worksheet with different data of its own. Tim's solution works for a single data cache. I will try using the XLSB format!